# How do you run coffeescript from Vim?

Tags: vim, coffeescript

I'm relatively new to Vim (from TextMate), and have been using [kchmck's Vim coffeescript plugin](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script). It's great, but I miss being able to cmd-R in TextMate to run snippets of coffeescript using [jashkenas's TextMate bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle). Anyone have any tips on setting this up with Vim?

Comment: Looks like the :CoffeeCompile already does the compilation. Are you looking for a way to run the resulting JS in node?

Comment: Exactly. It's not the most important thing, but it can be very satisfying to see results instantly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no experience with CoffeeScript but from your second link I gather that your document is given to a `coffee` command.

Did you try `:!coffe %`?

- `:!` to run an external command,
- `coffee` the external command,
- `%` expanded by Vim at the time of execution, represents the current file.

**EDIT**

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <D-r> :!coffee %<CR>
```

- `nnoremap` the mapping works in normal mode only,
- `<D-r>` is <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> after that comes the sequence of commands,
- `:!coffee %` the command,
- `<CR>` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This actually works. Now to figure out how to bind it to a key.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to be able to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to run in **both** command mode and edit mode, add this to your ~/.vimrc:

```
inoremap <D-r> <ESC>:!coffee %<CR>
nnoremap <D-r> :!coffee %<CR>
```

- `inoremap` will be called in edit mode
- `nnoremap` will be called in command mode

Answer (score 2):

For anybody looking at this now, `vim-coffee-script` now supports the `CoffeeRun` command. (I assume it didn't at the time this question was originally asked.)

> The `CoffeeRun` command compiles the current file or selected snippet and runs the resulting JavaScript. Output is shown at the bottom of the screen.

[CoffeeRun: Run some CoffeeScript](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script#coffeerun-run-some-coffeescript)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is currently offered by the plugin. Perhaps you should [file a feature request](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/issues)?

Alternatively, you could use the Vim plugin to do compilation and watch the compiled JS with something like [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), which would automatically re-run it every time the JS changes.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to run CoffeeScript inside vim is very convenient.  To setup this up first install [CoffeeScript support for vim from kchmck](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) (I use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for my installation).  Then just place the following in your vimrc file

```
imap <silent> <Leader>ss :w^M:!clear; mocha %^M                             
map <silent> <Leader>ss :w^M:!clear; mocha %^M
```

and you should be able to type your `leader key + zz` to run the current CoffeeScript file.  Note that this will automatically save the file before running the mocha tests.